# Command to perform a recursive chmod to make all .sh files within a directory executable?

Tags: command-line, chmod, executable, sh

Trying to perform a recursive chmod on all the .sh files in a directory to make them executable

Comment: Look into `find` and maybe `xargs`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To make this possible you can use the `find` command and search for all  files with a `.sh` extension and then run the `chmod` command on each one found:

```
find /directory/of/interest/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Information:

1. `-type f`: Normal files only (skip directories, symlinks, named pipes and sockets, and the special files found in /dev)
2. `-iname`: Ignore case in the name
3. `"*.sh"`: Globbing, telling the `find` command to search for files with ".sh" extension
4. `-exec chmod +x {}`: This tells the `find` command to carry out a `chmod` command on each found file. Making each executable
5. `\;`: Indicating end of command

Comment: I think that you could end your find command with `+` to minimize the number of execution (see the difference between terminating exec with `\;` vs `+`).

Comment: Do you mean terminating exec with \; vs \+?

Answer (score 3):

```
chmod u+x /dir_of_interest/**/*.sh
```

Credit to: https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11936/recursive-chmod-all-.sh-files-within-the-current-directory

Comment: You need `shopt -s globstar` in bash for that to work.

Comment: Works. But if there are too many files to update `unable to execute /usr/bin/chmod: Argument list too long` error occurs. Then we can use the answer by @George Udosen.