# Locate .srt files in different directories and change character encoding

Tags: command-line, scripts, files

I have a great script that I use to convert encoding in srt.files. 
I also created an alias for that script so I can enter the directory where I want to run the script and use my alias `konvert`.

However, I have now the the following scenario: more then 20 directories with srt.files inside. What should I do in order to point my script to all those directories with just one command?

Luckily all these directories are together inside one main directory, so I believe there should be an easy way to do this.

*Content of the script*

```
#!/bin/bash for file in *.srt; do iconv -f CP1250 -t UTF-8 -o "$file".utf "$file" && mv "$file".utf "$file"; done
```

Comment: @Zanna My script (I posted the code in my question) works great to convert .srt files when I  `cd`  into the directory where the files are stored. But I coudn't find the way to do that from a root directory that contains other directories with .srt files. Firstly I thought that I would find a way  by taking advantage of that script but in the end it comes out that the better and moste effective solution is by using a different command. That's why, ultimately, I accepted the solution in the answer with command `recode`. It really did the job.

Comment: Related: [Command to perform a recursive chmod to make all sh files in a directory executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889344/command-to-perform-a-recursive-chmod-to-make-all-sh-files-within-a-directory-ex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy enough to accomplish *without your script* by using the following command line (using the application `recode` rather than straight `iconv`) which should be run from the root directory of your srt files:

```
find . -name '*.srt' -type f -exec bash -c 'recode -v CP1250..UTF-8 "$0"' {} \;
```

The command line searches *recursively* for all srt files and when each is found `recode` works on each file to change character encoding from CP1250 to UTF-8. With `recode` the encoding alteration does not require the clumsy filename shifting required by `iconv`...

How cool is the command line :)

Comment: Thank you,   @andrew.46   your altered answer with the command `recode` did a better job than my last variation with command `iconv`. Although I had to install `recode` it was worth it!  :)

Comment: @DunavRajna This is great news! And I see as well that the askubuntu community has reopened your question so extra great news :)